# Proving a series converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that:

If $ 0 < x < 1$ and there is an $N$ such that $\vert{a_n}\vert^{1/n} \leq  1 - \frac{1}{n^x} $ for every $ N \leq n$

Then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tried to use the root test, but it didn't work. Anyone got an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Its in the inequality part, N is raised to x power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use comparison test in a fashion similar to proof of root test.

You have an estimation $|a_n| \le \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^n$ for big enough $n$. All that remains is to prove that series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^n$ converges. Then by comparison test your series will converge absolutely. Consider equality

$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^n = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{n^xn^{1-x}} = \left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{n^x}\right)^{n^{1-x}}.
$$
Now we will use simple fact: $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{t}\right)^t = \frac{1}{e}$. Then for big enough $n$ we have inequality $\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{n^x} < \frac{1}{2}$ since $x > 0$ and $e > 2$. And therefore we obtain an estimate
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^n \le \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n^{1-x}}
$$
Now, the series $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n^\alpha}}$$ converges for all $\alpha > 0$ and therefore the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^x}\right)^n$ also converges by comparison test (with $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n^\alpha}}$, $\alpha  = 1-x > 0$).